# Use json to populate a case switch statement in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, object, switch-statement

I have the following switch/case statement which returns data from the json object below. In reality this will be very long!

**Switch statement**

```
switch(val){
    case 'chicken':
        return json['meat']['main'][val]; 
        break;
    case 'beef':
        return json['meat']['main'][val]; 
        break
    case 'lamb':
        return json['meat']['main'][val]; 
        break;
    case 'pork':
        return json['meat']['main'][val]; 
        break;
    default:
        return '';
}
```

**json object**

```
json={
  "meat": {
    "main": {
      "chicken": "Roast chicken and vegetables",
      "beef": "Beef and Yorkshire pudding",
      "lamb": "Lamb shank with red currant gravy",
      "pork": "Pork and apple sauce",
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the switch statement is very repetitive as every case statement returns the same expression (although the value it returns will be different as it is accessing a variable key [val] in the object).

In reality my json file is huge, so I want to avoid manually typing out a case statement for each meat (chicken, beef, lamb, pork). Instead I would like to iterate through my json object getting the value at json['meat']['main'][i] (where i is a counter) to create each case. Is this possible? And if not, is there an alternative approach?

Many thanks!

Katie

Comment: can you explain a bit more of your use case? For the above case you might not need a switch statement. `return json.meat.main[val]` should work

Comment: Your `switch` statement doesn't make any sense. If you use `json['meat']['main'][val]`, you are directly accessing correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
let json = {
  "meat": {
    "main": {
      "chicken": "Roast chicken and vegetables",
      "beef": "Beef and Yorkshire pudding",
      "lamb": "Lamb shank with red currant gravy",
      "pork": "Pork and apple sauce",
    }
  }
}


const search = (obj, val) => {      
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  for (const key of keys) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
      if (key === val) {
        return obj[key]
      }
    } else {
      const description = search(obj[key], val)
      if (description) {
        return description
      }
    }
  }
  return ''
}


const description = search(json, 'beef')
console.log(description)
```

Comment: isn't it something like this? `return json.meat.main['chicken']`

Comment: I'm assuming `val` could be something like "apple", which wont fall under the "meat" category. So you can't do `json.meat.main['apple']` or `json.fruit.main['apple']`.

Comment: Yes. it makes sense if that is the case. but from the question he needs a simple return of meat.main['val']. `Instead I would like to iterate through my json object getting the value at json['meat']['main'][i] `

Comment: @twharmon - you have nailed it! That's so clever - loving your answer and it works perfectly when I put it into my real code, which is much more complex. Thank you so much! And you have interpreted my question exactly as I intended. You're right that I need everything to be variable, so would need to work for apple  and other things etc. Thanks again - really happy with this solution :-)